# Erro em função GROUP_CONCAT Access

Tags: sql, microsoft-access, group-concat

Estou realizando o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT e.titulo, 
       e.descricao, 
       e.obs, 
       e.cupom, 
       e.inicio, 
       e.fim, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.nome) AS teste 
FROM   ((eventos e INNER JOIN produtoseventos pe 
                 ON e.idevento = pe.idevento) 
        INNER JOIN produtos p 
                ON pe.idproduto = p.idproduto) 
WHERE  ( e.fim >= NOW ) 
       AND ( e.inicio <= NOW ) 
GROUP  BY e.idevento
```

Ao executa-lo ele retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me informa de onde vem esse erro?

Modelagem do Banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

O Access não suporta a função `GROUP_CONCAT`, uma possibilidade é utilizar as funções `First` e `Last`

```
SELECT
  e.idevento,
  e.titulo,
  e.descricao,
  e.obs,
  e.cupom,
  e.inicio,
  e.fim,
  First(p.nome) & IIf(COUNT(p.nome) > 1, "," & Last(p.nome)) AS nome
FROM ((eventos e
INNER JOIN produtoseventos pe
  ON e.idevento = pe.idevento)
INNER JOIN produtos p
  ON pe.idproduto = p.idproduto)
WHERE (e.fim >= NOW)
AND (e.inicio <= NOW)
GROUP BY e.idevento,
         e.titulo,
         e.descricao,
         e.obs,
         e.cupom,
         e.inicio,
         e.fim;
```

Comment: Agora ele exibe outro erro: https://imgur.com/a/uX0AK5J

Comment: Provavelmente relacionado ao GROUP BY no access, a resposta foi editada.

Comment: Continua com o mesmo erro... Mesmo assim muito obrigado!